# Cant find react error which child is missing key prop

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I get the very common **Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.** This is usually very easy to resolve but in this case its just impossible to me to figure out where the issue is created.

My stack trace:

```
 in hoc (created by Connect(hoc))
    in Connect(hoc) (at withTranslation.js:7)
    in hoc (at ConnectedProtectedRoutes.js:26)
    in Route (at ConnectedProtectedRoutes.js:44)
    in ProtectedRoutes (created by Connect(ProtectedRoutes))
```

withTranslation Component

```
export function withTranslation(CMP) {
    var hoc = class extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <CMP {...this.props} translate={translate} />
        }
    };
    return hoc;
}
```

ConnectedProtectedRoutes

```
const ProtectedRoutes = ({ token, authority, location }) => {
    var a = [
        createRouteWithRequirements(<Login key="1"/>, "/", [], { token, authority }, true),
        createRouteWithRequirements(<Login key="2"/>, "/login", [], { token, authority }),
        createRouteWithRequirements(<Register key="3"/>, "/register", [], { token, authority })
    ]

    return a
};

const createRouteWithRequirements = (component, url, requirements, injections, exact) => {
    return (
        <Route //this is -> in Route (at ConnectedProtectedRoutes.js:44)
            exact={!!exact}
            key={url}
            path={url}
            render={() => {
                if (requirements.includes("token") && !injections.token) {
                    return <Redirect to="/login" />
                }

                return component;
            }}
        />
    );
};
```

And the stack goes on but im guessing the issue is somewhere in there. Any clues?

Comment: Are you rendering anything else in the parent component that might have the same keys (eg `key="1"`)? If you have two separate lists mounted at the same time and some list elements have same key, then the warning would show up.

Answer (score 0):

## #metoo

Here's a non-answer that might be helpful: I was getting the exact same error and I could not guess why. I am generating a table with lots of rows and cols.

### No joy attempts

I went to extremes such as opening the React Tools Component inspector to all elements, including HTML ones. A mess, but necessary. I also tried logging all the keys to the browser console, copy/pasting them into a `sort | uniq |wc -l` vs a `wc -l`, and these yielded the same numbers. All my keys were distinct!

I checked over and over again and my children all had different keys. These keys were getting quite long, dotted from the keys from the elements above and absolutely no repetitions.

Except for one...

Even removing the (in)famous `<React.StrictMode>`, React kept rendering some parts twice. So, I checked all hooks to be sure that no cross updates were triggering multiple renders.

### Joy!

I decided to try the very last thing: `npm run build`.

**And the production version has no key repetition errors!**

This is a bit of a bummer, because we rely on the dev environment in order to speed it up. After all, building takes minutes, not seconds.

I am using:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
  },
```

I'm considering moving from `react-scripts` to `vite`. I'm not sure this would fix anything, but it would speed things up.

Please feel free to explain this to me in the comments. I'm sure it will be something edge, or *au contraire* quite obvious and dumb.

Answer (score -1):

In your ProtectedRoutes component you are defining an array and using it somewhere else. Hence, each array needs a key, this is why you are getting warning. So, handle the key for this array.

Comment: lemme try, i was confident that when defining an array like that the index was used as a key. brb

Comment: still getting the error, changed as shown in EDIT,pretty sure i tried that in the past as well. in very fact, i can see i pass the entire url as a key ( forgot i even did that as an attempt to avoid the issue )

Comment: I'm not a pro but I'm pretty sure keys are not handling automatically for arrays :) I was sure that will solve the problem. I can't see anything causes that error in your code now.

Comment: i know right? this has been popping up in my console for too long a time now, you can imagine the OCD triggering